# Executing SQL troubles

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I try to  execute my stored procedure but I have trouble with it.

One of the parameters pf the stored procedure is defined like that:

```
@MerchId [dbo].[intArray] READONLY,
```

And it's a user-defined table type.

Here is definition of the above type:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[intArray] AS TABLE ([num] [int] NULL)
```

Here is how I try to set value and execute:

```
exec    @return_value = [dbo].[SPMerchData],
        @MerchId = [1,2,3]
```

But I get a syntax error.

Any idea how can I set value to `@MerchId` variable to execute the stored procedure?

Comment: where are you passing `[dbo].[intArray]`..please create an minimal example to repro

Comment: I guess the idea was to pass  [1,2,3], but this won't work since SQL Server doesn't recognize this as table / array. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should declare a variable and pass it to your procedure:

```
DECLARE @t intArray;
INSERT INTO @t VALUES (1), (2), (3);

exec    @return_value = [dbo].[SPMerchData],
        @MerchId = @t
```